Programmatically setting VisualStateGroups for ColumnHeader results in weird animations
First off I am not very familiar with WPF so I am sorry if this is an obvious problem that I'm just not understanding.
I am trying to programmatically set the ColumnHeaderStyle for a WorkbookView and I am experiencing weird behavior with the ColumnHeaders not updating/being set correctly. When I create the same style within the XAML it works flawlessly as intended but as far as I can tell, I am not able to dynamically change/update the Converter function for the ColumnHeader when the ActiveTab changes.
My solution was to just create the style programmatically, that way I can pass in an object that will determine how the text for the columns is set but when I do this I experience the weird behavior and my ColumnHeaders seem to only sometimes update and will only to the left of whatever the right-most selected column is but even then the updating is very sporadic.
The CommonStates VisualStatesGroup seems to work as expected but I can't seem to get the SelectionStates to behave correctly.
I'm not sure why the MouseOver/Normal work correctly but the SelectionStates have seemingly undefined behavior when set programmatically. I have included the least amount of code that I could to show what I am dealing with.
I think think that the offending code preventing the animation from triggering correctly is this code here from my C# (full code block further down after XAML):
gridFactory.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) =>
{
    VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups((Grid)s).Add(commonStates);
    VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups((Grid)s).Add(selectionStates);
}));

This is my current XAML (I have turned off the reference to the XAML style for the WorkbookView, I left the style there to help explain what I am trying to achieve.):
<Window x:Class="SSGBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sg="http://schemas.spreadsheetgear.com/controls/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SSGBug" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:ColumnHeaderTextConverter x:Key="ColumnHeaderTextConverter"/>
            <Style x:Key="MyCustomColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="sg:ColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="sg:ColumnHeader">
                            <Grid x:Name="Root">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Fill="#FFF2F2F2" Stretch="Fill" />
                                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#FF688CAF"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding ColumnIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=sg:ColumnHeader, AncestorLevel=1}, Converter={StaticResource ColumnHeaderTextConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF000000" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFB7E7FB" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF000000" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFB7E7FB" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundRectangle" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <sg:WorkbookView x:Name="workbookView" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

using SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SSGBug
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            workbookView.ActiveTabChanged += WorkbookView_ActiveTabChanged;
        }

        private void WorkbookView_ActiveTabChanged(object sender, SpreadsheetGear.Windows.Controls.ActiveTabChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            workbookView.ColumnHeaderStyle = CustomStyles.CreateMyCustomColumnHeaderStyle();
        }
    }

    public class ColumnHeaderTextConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return "This will be a function call";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Not used.
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class CustomStyles
    {
        public static Style CreateMyCustomColumnHeaderStyle()
        {
            Style style = new(typeof(ColumnHeader));

            // Create the ControlTemplate
            ControlTemplate controlTemplate = new(typeof(ColumnHeader));

            // Define the Grid
            FrameworkElementFactory gridFactory = new(typeof(Grid))
            {
                Name = "Root"
            };

            // Define the BackgroundRectangle
            FrameworkElementFactory backgroundRectangleFactory = new(typeof(Rectangle))
            {
                Name = "BackgroundRectangle"
            };
            backgroundRectangleFactory.SetValue(Shape.FillProperty, new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0xF2, 0xF2, 0xF2)));
            backgroundRectangleFactory.SetValue(Shape.StretchProperty, Stretch.Fill);

            // Define the Border
            FrameworkElementFactory borderFactory = new(typeof(Border));
            borderFactory.SetValue(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0, 0, 1, 1));
            borderFactory.SetValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0x68, 0x8C, 0xAF)));

            // Define the TextBlock
            FrameworkElementFactory textBlockFactory = new(typeof(TextBlock));
            textBlockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
            textBlockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center);
            Binding binding = new("ColumnIndex")
            {
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(ColumnHeader), 1),
                // This is supposed to take a param but I removed that logic for this demo
                Converter = new ColumnHeaderTextConverter()
            };
            textBlockFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);

            // Add children to the Grid
            gridFactory.AppendChild(backgroundRectangleFactory);
            gridFactory.AppendChild(borderFactory);
            gridFactory.AppendChild(textBlockFactory);

            controlTemplate.VisualTree = gridFactory;

            // Create the VisualStateGroups
            #region Common States
            VisualStateGroup commonStates = new() { Name = "CommonStates" };
            #region Normal State
            VisualState normalState = new() { Name = "Normal" };
            Storyboard normalStoryboard = new();
            ColorAnimation normalColorAnimation = new()
            {
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Zero),
                //To = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0xF2, 0xF2, 0xF2)
                // Making this black for now to make it obvious
                To = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
            };
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(normalColorAnimation, "BackgroundRectangle");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(normalColorAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Fill).Color"));
            normalStoryboard.Children.Add(normalColorAnimation);
            normalState.Storyboard = normalStoryboard;
            #endregion
            #region Mouse Over
            VisualState mouseOverState = new() { Name = "MouseOver" };
            Storyboard mouseOverStoryboard = new();
            ColorAnimation mouseOverColorAnimation = new()
            {
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Zero),
                To = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0xB7, 0xE7, 0xFB)
            };
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(mouseOverColorAnimation, "BackgroundRectangle");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(mouseOverColorAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Fill).Color"));
            mouseOverStoryboard.Children.Add(mouseOverColorAnimation);
            mouseOverState.Storyboard = mouseOverStoryboard;
            #endregion
            commonStates.States.Add(normalState);
            commonStates.States.Add(mouseOverState);
            #endregion

            #region Selection States
            VisualStateGroup selectionStates = new() { Name = "SelectionStates" };
            #region Unselected
            VisualState unselectedState = new() { Name = "Unselected" };
            Storyboard unselectedStoryboard = new();
            ColorAnimation unselectedColorAnimation = new()
            {
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Zero),
                To = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
            };
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(unselectedColorAnimation, "BackgroundRectangle");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(unselectedColorAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Fill).Color"));
            unselectedStoryboard.Children.Add(unselectedColorAnimation);
            unselectedState.Storyboard = unselectedStoryboard;
            #endregion
            #region Selected
            VisualState selectedState = new() { Name = "Selected" };
            Storyboard selectedStoryboard = new();
            ColorAnimation selectedColorAnimation = new()
            {
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Zero),
                To = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0xB7, 0xE7, 0xFB)
            };
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(selectedColorAnimation, "BackgroundRectangle");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(selectedColorAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Fill).Color"));
            selectedStoryboard.Children.Add(selectedColorAnimation);
            selectedState.Storyboard = selectedStoryboard;
            #endregion
            selectionStates.States.Add(unselectedState);
            selectionStates.States.Add(selectedState);
            #endregion

            // I think this is what isn't working correctly?
            // Add VisualStateGroups to the template
            gridFactory.AddHandler(FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((s, e) =>
            {
                VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups((Grid)s).Add(commonStates);
                VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups((Grid)s).Add(selectionStates);
            }));

            // Set the control template
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.TemplateProperty, controlTemplate));

            return style;
        }
    }
}


Oh. FrameworkElementFactory is obsolete. According to Microsoft you should no longer use it to create UI elements. Why don't you use XAML? It really doesn't make sense to go the hard and ugly route and create styles and templates using C#. You can add the XAML Style to a ResourceDictionary and then retrieve using C# to assign it to your control.

@BionicCode The reason I didn't use XAML is because I need to be able to change the "Converter" or pass in arguments for the TextBlock when the ActiveTab changes and as far as I could figure out, the only way to be able to do that would be programmatically. I'm not even quite sure what to Google in order to find what I'm looking for but if there's a way to give/set the TextBlock's Converter. We have ~10 Spreadsheets and each on has ~5 tabs so that would be 50 unique XAML style/Converters which I was hoping to avoid, but if that's the only way then so be it.

One option is to create the Style in XAML and then clone it in C# to modify and finally apply it. Honestly, your problem seems a bit odd. It's not very common to dynamically change a Style. Usually, a Style configures a control. You would change the binding source of the bindings used in the style. Or you could modify/replace resources that are referenced using {DynamicResource}. The Style itself is static.

Or you could use triggers to dynamically switch between styles. To change binding converters during runtime you would have to add the converter to a ResourceDictionary. Then you can replace the converter instance at any time. You only have to clone and reapply the Style.  I hope I could give you some ideas to consider.
